# Python: Checking unique category for each users

Tags: python, pandas

I have a user table that includes their items and other information

I need to choose the only a user who has only one item type, else drop from dataframe.
Example table:

```
|customer |items   |levels   |
| -------| ------- | ------- |
|  a    |  x     | 0    |
|  a    |  x     | 1    |
|  a    |  y     | 0    |
|  a    |  y     | 0    |
|  b    |  t     | 0    |
|  b    |  t     | 1    |
|  b    |  t     | 1    |
|  b    |  t     | 3    |
```

so drop customer "a"

I can check like this:

```
df.groupby('customer').agg({'items':'nunique'})
```

and joined the two tables but I am not sure how efficient.

Do we have more efficient way to drop that values(we have also multiple record so I am not sure how to use `drop_duplicate`)

Comment: Would you be able to post expected output? i think i have an answer, but just want to make sure that's the output your looking for

Comment: I upvoted this question, i'm interested in the correct answer, i have removed mine for brevity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `transform`

```
con=df.groupby('customer')['item'].transform('nunique')==1
df1=df[con].copy()
```

To fix your output

```
s=df.groupby('customer').agg({'items':'nunique'})
df1=df.loc[df.customer.isin(s[s==1].index)].copy()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is more efficient but you can also use: df1 = df[df.groupby('customer')['items'].transform('nunique')==1]

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
new_df=df.groupby('customer').filter(lambda x: x['items'].nunique()==1)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  customer items  levels
4        b     t       0
5        b     t       1
6        b     t       1
7        b     t       3
```